Can someone explain me how to add GLFW in a new CLion project?
I've been learning Cpp for a little while now, and I want to import libraires and such. But I haven't been able to import and use anything so far... I downloaded the binaries for GLFW, copied the include folder into my CLion project's root folder. And then what? I'm supposed to link it, but HOW??? There's no help whatsoever, everyone on every tutorial just acts like it's already done and it's magic or you already OBVIOUSLY know how to do it.
I have no idea what I'm doing, I will probably get roasted bc this platform is toxic, but can someone just help me please 
So far this is the error I'm getting:
====================[ Build | LearnOpenGL | Debug ]=============================
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\dev\LearnOpenGL\cmake-build-debug --target LearnOpenGL -j 10
[0/1] Re-running CMake...
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindGLFW.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "GLFW", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "GLFW" with any of
  the following names:

    GLFWConfig.cmake
    glfw-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "GLFW" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "GLFW_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "GLFW"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
FAILED: build.ninja 
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --regenerate-during-build -SC:\dev\LearnOpenGL -BC:\dev\LearnOpenGL\cmake-build-debug

So far my CMakeLists.txt looks like that...
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(LearnOpenGL)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

find_package(GLFW REQUIRED)

add_executable(LearnOpenGL main.cpp)

include_directories(./include)
target_link_libraries("${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}" PRIVATE glfw)

Project structure is something like:
Root
|-- include
|  |-- GLFW
|  |  |-- glfw3.h
|  |  |-- glfwnative.h
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- main.cpp

But it's not linking or something... Not sure :(
I tied using CPM:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(LearnOpenGL)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

include(cmake/CPM.cmake)
CPMAddPackage("gh:glfw/glfw#3.4")
CPMAddPackage("gh:Dav1dde/glad#v2.0.6")

target_link_libraries(main glad glfw)

But now it's glad that doesn't want to work at all...

'Copied the include folder', that's a mistake. You should never need to copy anything. As the error message says CMake is failing the find the library you installed. So now things get complicated. Where have you installed glfw? Where is cmake looking for glfw? These are the kind of questions you should ask. IDK the answers but I do know that you are much more likely to have success with 3rd party libraries if you are using a package manager to install them. Most package managers are 'cmake aware'. So that's what you should do next.

Just in case it's not clear. You've misunderstood the nature of the problem, it's not failing to link, that would be shown with an error from your linker. What you have is an error from cmake, so the problem is that cmale has failed to find GLFW, that's an error because of find_package(GLFW REQUIRED) without REQUIRED you would not get a cmake error, but then you'll get a link error instead.

The other thing I'd consider is not using cmake. cmake is fine, but since you are learning it might be better to remove it from the build and just use your compiler directly. Conceptually that's a much simpler way to go. Once you are happy with how your compiler works you will find it easier to introduce cmake.

And just to emphasise one more time. Install your 3rd party libraries (preferably with a package manager) but then leave them where they are, never copy anything. The model is that you tell your compiler or build system where the installation is. Beginner often try to copy stuff to where they think the compiler might be looking but generally that just leads to more trouble.

How are y'all helping here? I'm completely new and just saying "never copy anything" doesn't mean anything??? How are you supposed to add it to your project otherwise??? Also there are no CMAKE include file or whataver that's called in the GLFW archive... I have like 40 CMake files and I have tried many things but nothing worked so far. I tried using CPM but it won't work with glad for some reason

If you do not want to fight CMake, just download Glitter. It's a premade CMake project that automatically builds GLFW, GLAD, and a few other libraries for you.

@Lolou. Ultimately it's up to you to teach yourself how to build things in your build environment. Everyone's situation is different and so what you do is different. This how C++ works, there is no way of using libraries that is built into C++ itself. You don't add third party libraries to your project, you tell your project where you have installed them. Otherwise you end up with 20 different copies of your third party library, all of which will need updating when a new version is released.

The windows binaries do not ship anything that CMake can work with.
The approach you tried is this one but it expects the GLFW installation to contain its glfw3Config.cmake file, which you don't.
If you are just at the start of your learning journey you should consider using a package manager like vcpkg or conan, which is orders of magnitude less work than figuring out how to link individual libraries from the documentation.
If you are too stubborn to use a package manager, the common solution is to create and use an IMPORTED target:
add_library(glfw IMPORTED SHARED)
set_target_properties(glfw PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION lib-vc2022/glfw3.dll
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB lib-vc2022/glfw3dll.lib
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_LIBRARIES include)
target_link_libraries(LearnOpenGL PUBLIC glfw)

To read more about this see It's time to do CMake right and Modern CMake

I don't use VC. And also there are no lib nor dll in the downloads I got. I just downloaded it from the site.

That is impossible. Unless you downloaded the source code or a binary release for a different platform. (in which case they'd be .so or .dylib files) As for VC: It's a trivial matter of selecting a different directory.

@Lolou. 'I just downloaded it from the site'. As has been said, use a package manager. I know it's another tool to learn but it will very quickly pay dividends because the package will be installed correctly, automatically be for the correct platform, most likely will be cmake compatible, very easy to update etc. etc.

That's not helping tbh
Explain me how to do it lol

You have failed to answer even the most basic of questions: which file did you download? Coming back two weeks later with an entitled reponse like "explain me how to do it lol" without doing any research of your own is not going to help your cause. Again, if you don't care about any of this, just get Glitter because it always works.
